# if dijit id is same as variable name IE10 throws exception ex id1=dijit.byId('id1')

Tags: internet-explorer, dojo

if dijit id is same as variable name IE10 throws exception

ex:

```
var id1=dijit.byId('id1')  -> throws exception
```

if we change either id or variable name it works. i.e.

```
id2=dijit.byId('id1')
```

I have 100 such cases in my code.

Please suggest a one or two line changes which would change IE property.

Comment: Are you sure you used quotes? In your second example you didn't put quotes around `id1`.

Comment: It is a mistyping i have used id2=dijit.byId('id1')

Comment: what is the exception?